# listbox selection not retaining on postback (yes i check for postback)

Tags: asp.net, .net, listbox, postback, asp.net-4.0

I have a listbox in an asp.net webpage.

I select item 2. if i have autopostback on, this reloads the page and selects item1.
I only databind the page on first load (!IsPostback), have stepped through and verified this. It's not rebinding or repopulating the list, it just selects the first item again, removing the second item selection.

Furthermore, the onselectedindexchanged event only fires AFTER postback so i cannot retain the selected index in a session variable to set on postback...

page is set to viewstateenabled, controls set to viewstateenabled, viewstatemode is enabled.

How do I set it up so that the 2nd item is still selected on postback? My code is very straightforward but I'll post it...

```
<asp:ListBox ID="AvailableRepairSelection" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
            onselectedindexchanged="AvailableRepairSelection_SelectedIndexChanged" 
            ViewStateMode="Enabled"></asp:ListBox>
```

Again, I select item 2, page posts back, item1 is highlighted.

relevant parts of codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            int selectedmodel = Convert.ToInt32(Session["selectedModel"]);
            List<AvailableRepair> Repairs = (from r in Database.instance().AvailableRepairs
                                             where r.modelid == selectedmodel
                                             select r).ToList<AvailableRepair>();
            foreach (AvailableRepair repair in Repairs)
            {
                AvailableRepairSelection.Items.Add(new ListItem(repair.repair + ": " + repair.description + "- " + repair.cost, repair.cost));
            }
        }
    }
```

PLEASE NOTE that there is more to this page but I have isolated the only issues to be with these snippets. So dont advise me how to change my page or why i am posting back a selection when theres nothing but a listbox in the page.

Comment: I have added your code to a page and on postback, it retains the selected item, you will need to post the indexchanged code too.

Comment: Do each of the repair items in the ListBox have a unique value? i.e. the value of the cost property on the Repair type?

Comment: that was the problem @devdigital, i was dumb and didnt realize my test db had identical values because i am using cost for the value. changed it to use id:cost and separate to get cost.